# Crs setting in scikit mobility. Python

Tags: python, gps, scikits

I am trying to use scikit mobility to recreate trajectories and stop location from GPS https://scikit-mobility.github.io/scikit-mobility/reference/data_structures.html#module-skmob.core.trajectorydataframe

By using TrajDataFrame and then I am applying

```
stdf = detection.stay_locations(tdf, stop_radius_factor=0.5, minutes_for_a_stop=20.0, spatial_radius_km=0.2, leaving_time=True)
```

my data looks the same as in example but I am getting the error ''TrajDataFrame' object has no attribute '_crs''. CRS is just optional and even when I added the error is appearing. Does anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been solved in the current version (v1.3.1), which works for versions of python >= 3.8.

If you are using it in Google Colab (for which version 3.8 is not available yet), after having installed scikit-mobility, you need to downgrade the pandas library to version 1.2.5:

`!pip install pandas==1.2.5`

Then, the problem should be solved. See also this solved issue: https://github.com/scikit-mobility/scikit-mobility/issues/204

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to play around with the Markov Diary Generator, so i had to import the following packages:

```
import skmob
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from skmob.models.epr import Ditras
from skmob.models.markov_diary_generator import MarkovDiaryGenerator
from skmob.preprocessing import filtering, compression, detection, clustering
```

I'm using scikit-mobility version **v1.3.1**

Finally this worked for me:

1. `conda create -n skmob pip python=3.9 rtree`
2. `conda activate skmob`
3. `conda install -n skmob pyproj urllib3 chardet markupsafe`
4. `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-mobility`
5. `pip install --upgrade fiona geopandas`
6. `pip uninstall geopandas folium geojson pandas statsmodels`
7. `pip install geopandas==0.10.2 folium==0.12.1.post1 geojson==2.5.0 pandas==1.1.5 statsmodels==0.13.0`
8. `pip uninstall python-igraph`
9. `pip install python-igraph==0.9.1`
10. `pip uninstall numpy`
11. `pip install numpy==1.23`